# fastest alternative to if-else or switch-case

Tags: c, algorithm

I have the following definition:

```
typedef enum
{
    def   = 0,
    m1    = 1,
    m2    = 2,
    m3    = 4,
    m4    = 6,
    m5    = 17,
    m6    = 33,
    m7    = 41,
    m8    = 47,
    m9    = 50,
    m10   = 51,
    m11   = 58,
    m12   = 89,
    m13   = 132,
    m14   = 135
} my_enums;
```

And I looking for a fastest way to check if an argument to a function falls in one of these values, m1..m14. The obvious implementation would be if (p == m1 || p == m2 ...)  or switch-case alternative.

Is there something faster? The values of m1~m14 are fixed and can't be in contiguous range.

Thanks.

Comment: What your compiler produces for the `switch` solution isn't fast enough?

Comment: Please clarify. Fastest for the developer to type in? Or fastest for the computer to execute?

Comment: @Kevin, fastest in terms of CPU cycles.

Comment: Since the values are in order, you can perform a binary search. But there are few items, you may get little performance improvement.

Comment: @DyP, I can't say the compiler produces slow code, but enum may grow and I worry this would be a bottleneck.

Comment: You may want to look at [perfect hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) - it will work well even if your values are scattered on a large range.

Comment: "I worry this would be a bottleneck". You could just do it the simplest, most straightforward way. When (if ever) it becomes an actual bottleneck, then you could refactor to something faster.

Comment: @hatchet: And not waste my time on premature optimization? Where do you get these crazy ideas?

Comment: @JimMischel - "Where do you get these crazy ideas?" From having to maintain code written by someone who was too clever by half.

Comment: Generally there is no such thing like a "fastest" way to do such things. This depends on a whole of parameters of your platform. There are guys out there that write compilers and do nothing else than such optimizations all day. Trust them.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest I can think of offhand would be an array of bytes from 0 to 135. Set the value to 1 if the the item is one of your valid enums, and 0 if it's not. Then you can write:

```
if (valuesArray[x])
    YahooItsGood();
```

That doesn't work, of course, if your range is huge.

If the value passed in can be out of that range, then you'll need a little more logic:

```
if (x >= 0 && x < 136 && valuesArray[x])
    YahooItsGood();
```

Of course, you really only need one bit per item, so you could save a lot of memory by using an array that's 1/8 the size. The logic to test a value becomes slightly more involved, but it's still going to be faster than a series of if/else, or a binary search.

If you have a much larger set, then you'll probably want to build a hash table. It won't be as fast as a direct lookup, but it'll use a whole lot less memory when the range of values is much larger.

Comment: "could save a lot of memory" -- up to 118 bytes! :)

Comment: @JakobBorg, 118 bytes isn't a lot these days. The real downside to using bits vs. bytes is that the table is much harder to generate and read.

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest you can think of"? This depends on a lot of factors, probably you compiler knows much better for some version of "fastest".

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah, I thought my smiley indicated what I thought of that particular trade-off.

Comment: @JensGustedt: As I said, it's the fastest *I* can think of offhand. The compiler might very well have a better way. But I don't know about it.

Comment: @JakobBorg: That was an artifact of editing. I had a big discussion in there about much larger sets taking 2 gigabytes, etc. When I edited that out I left the "save a lot of memory." Oh, well.

Comment: @JimMischel, it was not the "think of" that I was questioning but your  idea of "fastest". What will be fast in one situation, might be a pain in another. There is no such thing.

Comment: These days, memory is cheap, but cache line misses aren't. If you have any data for such an algorithm, it should ideally fit into one cache line (64 bytes). You should ensure that your byte array is suitably aligned by using platform/compiler specific attributes. Ideally, you could force the compiler to put the data into the code section so that it'd likely be in the cache line where the code already is!

Answer (score 7):

A switch statement would be the better option. It helps to know the tricks the compiler can employ to make a switch statement very optimal (in most cases). Many times, better than what you might come up with yourself.

If the values are non contiguous, the compiler can resort to a static binary decision tree with O(log(n)) performance. For a contiguous value list, it will construct a jump table, which is O(1). By comparison, an if-else construct is O(n).

I would suggest you fully understand what you can get out of a switch statement before resorting to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea if you can guarantee that the input will be 8 bits wide: create a static int array of size 256, with 1 at the indices specified by your enum, and 0 everywhere else. Then all you have to do is one array lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer binary search, because the values are in order.

One defines an array:

```
  my_enums enumv[17] = {def, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12, m13, m14, -1, -1};
```

(The last 2 values are centinels, they have no effect in the results).

Then one does a binary search:

```
  int s = 0;
  for (int i = 8; i; i /= 2)
        if (p >= enumv[s+i])
           s += i;
  if ( p >= 0 && p == enumv[s])
     printf("Happy\n");
  else
     printf("Unhappy\n");
```

If you don't want all the "for" thing and, since you have just 15 values, this algorithm can be unrolled and written "at hand", to be faster:

```
  int s = 0;
  s += 8*(p >= enumv[s+8]); 
  s += 4*(p >= enumv[s+4]);
  s += 2*(p >= enumv[s+2]);
  s +=   (p >= enumv[s+1]);

  if (p >= 0 && p == enumv[s])
     printf("Happy\n");
  else
     printf("Unhappy\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2-cents - divide and conquer using bitwise operations on MSBs. Seeing as 32 is close to the median here, start by splitting the table in half with

```
    if (p & 32)
```

next level would be comparing the false case with (p & 4) and the true case with (p & 64) - this leaves you with exactly 3 options in each branch (that could be covered by a logical or), except the one between 32 and 64, which can be further broken down using (p & 48) (this one isn't a round power of 2 so it works only on some cases, I guess only where the MSBs are equal)

the benefit here is that you've done a binary search (even in the worst case where your numbers are contiguous, you fall to a binary search over the entire region, still log(MAX_N)), and you're doing so using cheap bitwise operations that a could compiler may be able to predicate (or you can go ahead and do it yourself)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(p/7==0 && (p%6!=3 ||p%6!=5))
 // p is present, p = 0,1,2,4,6
if(p==17||p==33.....remaining 7 numbers)
//p is present
```

so you got them reduced from 14 condition evaluations to 12...
Maybe try to find some relations among the values like I did above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the fastest one, bit operation should be faster than byte.

You can have 17 Octets. For each bit, if the bit is what you want, mark it as 1, otherwise 0. For every look-up, simply calculate the Octet id and the bit you want to check, then check it and you get the result.